# Why npm fails to install jqueryui package?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install jqueryui and its typescript from npm. While jquery packages have been successfully installed, both packages for jqueryui has failed. Please note that I'm able to browse jqueryui packages if I visit site, npmjs.com

Debug data:
npm -v
3.10.10

Packages location:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jqueryui
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jqueryui

Comamnds:
npm install --save jqueryui
npm install --save @types/jqueryui

Error

- jqueryui' is not in the npm registry.
- @types/jqueryui' is not in the npm registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this and it works:

```
$ npm install --save jqueryui
npm-t1@1.0.0 /home/rsp/node/test/npm-t1
└── jqueryui@1.11.1 

npm WARN npm-t1@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN npm-t1@1.0.0 No repository field.

$ npm install --save @types/jqueryui
npm-t1@1.0.0 /home/rsp/node/test/npm-t1
└─┬ @types/jqueryui@1.11.32 
  └── @types/jquery@2.0.40 

npm WARN npm-t1@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN npm-t1@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

(those warnings are because I don't have certain fields in the package.json of a test project that I just created.)

It seems that you may be using some other registry than the public one.

See:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config
- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

Comment: Yes I'm using my corporate proxy since direct access is blocked. I've little knowledge on registry, I was unsure on why jquery is working while jqueryui is not.

Comment: I was able to install the packages if I connect to company wifi. Please note that the I'm still using company's proxy server than public registry. Please let me know if there could be some other issue. -- I'll mark this as an answer.